# p5.js- Setting input type to password

Tags: html, forms, p5.js

fairly new programmer here.

I've recently been trying to use p5.js to create a username and password form. It's worked wonderfully, at least until I needed to make the password field private (and look like a password field)

I know that there is the `<input type="password">` option in HTML, but I was wondering how to incorporate this somehow into my p5.js code.

Thank you!

My code:

```javascript
password = createInput();
password.position(70, 265);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to answer questions like this is to read through [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/). [Here](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createInput) is the reference for the `createInput()` function.

> `createInput([value], [type])`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `value`   String: default value of the input box `type`   String: type of
>   text, ie text, password etc. Defaults to text

So it sounds like you probably want to do something like this:

```
password = createInput('', 'password');
```

Also note that you can probably use the `createElement()` and `attribute()` function to build the element manually.